# Wide String vs String , Does it affect performance in Windows C++

Tags: c++, performance, widestring

I'm handling a lot of Unicode file paths in my C++ project. I peform a check in my code , if they are fine enough to fit in Multibyte String , i keep it as a normal string (std::string) variable,where else if the string doesn't fit in Multibyte i use it as a wide char string.

My question is whether i can use the paths totally as wstrings ..? would it affect performance, i have to do some string manipulations,file open, create,rename and delete with the wstring. So rather that checking multibyte or wide char string, i would like to use it directly as wstring which would save me a lot of if/else.

```
bool IsUnicodeWString(const std::wstring &_WStr)
{
  WCHAR* posUnicodePath = (WCHAR*)_WStr.c_str();
  size_t multiByteLen = wcstombs(NULL, posUnicodePath, 0) + 1;
  int tempLength = 0;
  if (multiByteLen > 0)
  {
    TCHAR* _tmpTChar = new TCHAR[multiByteLen + 1];
    memset(_tmpTChar, '\0', multiByteLen + 1);
    tempLength = wcstombs(_tmpTChar, posUnicodePath, multiByteLen);
    if (tempLength == std::string::npos)
    {
      multiByteLen = 0;
    }
    delete[] _tmpTChar;
  }
  if(multiByteLen == 0 || multiByteLen == std::string::npos) { // Is Unicode file 
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

if(IsUnicodeWString) {
        // Use wstring [ Operations - String Manipulations,FilePath used for Open,Read,Write,Create,Delete,Rename,etc]
} else {
        //string  [ Operations - String Manipulations,FilePath used for Open,Read,Write,Create,Delete,Rename,etc]
}
```

Please share your thoughts ...

Comment: You should either make everything use `std::wstring` unconditionally and forget storing MBCS in `std::string` altogether, or else switch to UTF-8 instead of MBCS so there is no possibiity of data loss (MBCS is not loss-less) and then convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 when calling API functions that require UTF-16.

Comment: Worry about making it correct before you worry about the speed.  Sticking to one format will simplify the code, and that will make it much simpler to make it correct.

Comment: My opinion is that your checking and conversion function is going to be far more expensive than just using wide strings everywhere.

Comment: Nearly all of Windows (that uses strings at all) uses wide strings internally, so in most cases using a wide-string version is cheaper than using a narrow-string version. Most narrow-string functions just create an equivalent wide string, then call the wide-string function.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the impelemtnation. Do not use them, instead use `_wstr` or just get rid of the underscore. The cast is also unnecessary. Use `&_wstr[0]`.

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: thanks for the comments, but does wstring[wchar_t] have any effect on performance in Windows C++ ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, Try to use `wchar_t` as much as posible. Because it is default character representation in Windows, kernel also using `wchar_t` as default. All of ANSI APIs are the wrapper of UNICODE APIs. If you disassembly ANSI APIs, you will known the truth.

Also, Use `ATL::CString` instead `std::(w)string` if possible. Because its used reference counting and the size of the class is equal to pointer size (4 bytes in 32-bits and 8 bytes in 64-bits). That mean you can return `ATL::CString` directly from the functions without performance penalty.